# Server 2012R2 other users tile

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I want to know if we can hide the other user tile while logging in to windows server 2012R2, i found some answers like 
a.    Go to Start.
b.    Type “gpedit.msc” without the quotes and press enter.
c.    Go to Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / Security Options.
d.    In the right-hand pane double click the policy: Interactive logon: Do not display last user name. This security setting determines whether the name of the last user to log on to the computer is displayed in the Windows logon screen.
e.    Select and set the radio button of Disabled.
f.     Click Apply and click OK.

and other things as well but in vain.

please someone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

As administrator, run `regedit.exe` and browse to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList]` (create the subkeys as necessary). In this key, create 1 DWORD value for each user account you wish to hide, with the name being the name of the user account, with the value 0 to hide it. E.g. to hide the user "RandomUser", you would create the following registry value (shown in the registry key export format):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList]
"RandomUser"=dword:00000000
```

You may need to reboot the server afterwards for this to take effect.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, the machine i have set up is the new one and just want the other user tile to hide..it seems this will hide the other users who logged in previously? while i want the tile to completely go away

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Is your new server in a domain? If so, did you set it in the domain group policy (which takes precedence) or the local group policy?

Comment: Hi, yes i added it to the domain and which domain policy i need to set?

Comment: Log onto the domain controller, run the Group Policy Editor, and run the Group Policy Modelling Wizard for your 2012R2 server. Check the results to see if that group policy setting is already enabled/disabled. You can test it by putting your server into its own OU (possibly under whatever OU you already have it in), create a new test group policy and link it into that OU, promote it to the top priority in the list of group policies for that OU, and in that group policy, enable the "Interactive logon: Do not display last user name" policy setting. Reboot your 2012R2 server and test.

Comment: i enabled Interactive logon: Do not display last user name"  in default domain policy just to check if works but still in vain

Comment: You need to check if that policy setting is in effect for the server; run the Group Policy Modelling Wizard, selecting your server and any user (we're only interested in the computer configuration, so the user doesn't matter) and go through the results to see what the policy setting actually is. If it is set correctly, it's possible that your server isn't loading domain group policies correctly. In that case, run `gpresult /h gpreport.html` on your server to see if there are any issues with group policy processing.